# Mapbox install dependencies failed

Tags: android, maven, gradle, mapbox

i followed this tutorial to install MapBox https://medium.com/fabcoding/mapbox-tutorial-for-android-map-geolocation-markers-bd9255947d99https://medium.com/fabcoding/mapbox-tutorial-for-android-map-geolocation-markers-bd9255947d99

after i added the following dependencies to gradle and sync :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.miniprojetandroid"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    //ROOM
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.0'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:4.3.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.8.1'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-places-v7:0.7.0'
    implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-geocoder:1.0.0@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v7:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-markerview-v7:0.2.0'

    //Material
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

I obtained error message when launching the application :

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library [com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-geocoder:1.0.0] C:\Users\Fares\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b8f13035bf89de10e6748e7ed482a3bc\jetified-mapbox-android-geocoder-1.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 14
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 15,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.mapbox.geocoder" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

What i am supposed to do in this kind of bugs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this error, you would have to increase the minimum SDK version from 14 to 15.

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.miniprojetandroid"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

However this example is using outdated versions of Mapbox SDKs. I would recommend to follow this documentation to install the Mapbox SDKs:

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/

Then you have this choice of examples you can choose from:

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/